# Android in Eclipse: startup object?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse. I've created 2 Android hello-world style apps. They have identical index.htmls in /assets/www and identical app.js files in /app.

Upon running, one app shows the index.html in the emulator, the other app shows the values of the strings in res\values\strings.xml (ie a heading of the ActivityName, and below it "Hello, (ActivityName)!"

I can't find anything in the project properties, the AndroidManifest.xml, anywhere that says how a project starts up, the code entry point. Where is it?

(waiting for the usual Eclipse answer: "you have to install a plugin" :)  ).

Comment: Did you try the hello world app at the [Android Developer Resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" > //shows the name of your application 

    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" //label of your activity    
              android:name=".Temp2Activity" >   // Activity Name     

    <intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> //The layout attach with that activity.
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  // LAUNCHER showing this activity in entry point of your application
    </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

So here within the activity tag < category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />"
showing that it will be the entry point (LAUNCHER) of your application.

Answer (score 4):

In your AndroidManifest.xml there is the following

There is a section as follows

```
<activity android:name=".HelloWorld" ....>
```

HelloWorld is the class that starts.

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. The startup code is in the /src/proj/activityname.java file. Thanks.